# MongoDB: How to execute a query to result of another query (nested queries)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to apply a set of filters (queries) to a collection. By default, the MongoDB applies `AND` operator to all queries submitted to `find` function. Instead of whole `AND` I need to apply each query sequentially (one by one). That is, I need to run the first-query and get a set of documents, run the second-query to result of first-query, and so on.

Is this Possible?

```
db.list.find({..q1..}).find({..q2..}).find({..q3..});
```

Instead Of:

```
db.list.find({..q1..}, {..q2..}, {..q3..});
```

*Why do I need this?*

Bcoz, the second-query needs to apply an aggregate function to result of first-query, instead of applying the aggregate to whole collection.

Comment: First and second queries do the same operation. Seems it obvious..

Comment: But first query is currently not possible in MongoDB. Thats what my question is how to achieve the first query.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible in MongoDB. You can write nested queries as per the requirement.Even in my application I created nested MongoDb queries.If you are familiar with  SQL syntax then compare this with **in** of sql syntax:

```
     select cname from table where cid in (select .....)
```

In the same way you can create nested MongoDB queries on different collections also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solves the problem but have to be careful about performance of $in operator in nested queries.

Comment: Yes, definitely you need to be concern that factor also before writing nested queries.And if it solves your problem then accept it so others having same problem will get solution.